# VS2010 assembly info suddenly stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Just in time for a critical release, the Assembly Information dialog stopped working for multiple projects.  The AssemblyInfo files are still there, unchanged, but the Assembly Information dialog has all blank fields.  Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this or if it is a sign of other issues?

Comment: Did you edit AssemblyInfo files in third party editor ? I guess that might be the cause

Comment: The only add on I use is BuildVersionIncrement, but that's nothing new.

Answer (score 0):

BuildVersionIncrement is an plugin for VS 2005/2008 and is not needed in VS2010. I would prefer you disable it as you can achieve the same with VS2010 using

```
AssemblyVersion=1.0.*
```

where VS2010 automaticly increments the "*"